# Changing LDAP schema casts Confluence AD integration unoperable

Tags: active-directory, ldap, schema

I have had our instance of Atlassian Confluence configured to be integrated with our Active Directory.

In AD, all the users were being created under default `Users` folder in Active Directory Users and Computers.

We have decided to introduce cleaner separation and have created an Organizational Units structure in AD. Under root we have created `Managed` OU, and under it - `Users` OU and all user accounts were moved under Users OU.

Now I though that to let the Confluence AD integration engine "know" where to look for user accounts now, I only need to adjust the BaseDN and prepand it with ou=Managed so it is aware that it is looking for cn=Users but under ou=Managed. That didn't work.

How should I adjust LDAP schema root in a client application for it to be able to look for users in OU that then in a default folder.

Comment: Probably because the users are no longer in the Users Well Known Container but are in a new OU named Users, so it's not CN=Users, its OU=Users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CN denotes a common name and is used to denote well-known AD containers such as Users, Computers, System, etc. When create your own `Users` OU, you've done just that, create an OU, so you no longer use the `CN=` syntax, you use the `OU=` syntax for that part of the path. In the example you've provided, if you're just specifying a path to the objects, you wouldn't have a `CN=` anywhere.

If your AD domain was named `ad.example.com`, you would use this path based on the details you've provided:

```
OU=Users,OU=Managed,DC=ad,DC=example,dc=com
```